# Does anyone have a working example of JSON insert/select in OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb

Select query doesn't work for JSON in OrientDB. Can someone provide with a working example showcasing two things:

1. Inserting JSON data correctly
2. Querying JSON data

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what you have tried and what went wrong?

Comment: @theoutlander: did you found the solution to it? Any working example? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @K.K sorry I moved on from OrientDB so can't accept an answer below either because I have no way of verifying it.

Answer (score 4):

1.Use **"content"** to implement JSON insert.

For Example-
`insert into Person content {"name":"nawab","age":25}`

for this to run,you must have prior configuration as-
1.Create a Vertex by-

```
create class Person extends V
```

2.Then Create Property **name** and **age**

`create property Person.name string`
`create property Person.age integer`

Answer (score 3):

Here you go! I have been trying to figure this out for a while now and finally got it to work. :)

Run the following sql commands as displayed:

```
create class EXAMPLE

/* The trick is: Do not 'CREATE' the property with any type */

insert into EXAMPLE (my_prop) values ({"name": "James", "age": 23})
insert into EXAMPLE (my_prop) values ({"name": "Harden", "age": 24})

/* Fetch the fields inside the JSON */
select my_prop.name from example
select my_prop.age from example where my_prop.name like 'James'
```

I read this example from the book: [Getting Started with OrientDB By Claudio Tesoriero](https://books.google.com/books?id=nUD3fWJ3u_8C&pg=PT105&lpg=PT105&dq=insert+JSON+into+records+orientdb&source=bl&ots=VQ_gNtJgIy&sig=2cN5_VELl076VFmanC8k1kTLsbY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xMEHVdHtNIWpogSJ3IEI&ved=0CFIQ6AEwCQ#v=snippet&q=JSON&f=false)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This question continues in the OrientDB group [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/orient-database/bNcurjCpvSY/discussion). Have you tried if everything work?

Comment: Hi @Lvca ! is there any way to add string type key in object like {'itemid':123} instead of {itemid: 1234 } My use-case is I want to use rids as key like {'#12:23':123}...